# Dot product for correlation with complex numbers

Tags: python, numpy

OK, this question probably has a very simple answer, but I've been searching for quite a while with no luck...

I want to get the dot product of 2 complex numbers in complex-plane-space. However, np.dot and np.vdot both give the wrong result.

Example of what I WANT to do:

```
a = 1+1j
b = 1-1j
dot(a,b) == 0
```

What I actually get:

```
np.dot(a,b) == 2+0j
np.vdot(a,b) == 0-2j
np.conj(a)*b == 0-2j
```

I am able to get what I want using this rather clumsy expression (edit for readability):

```
a.real*b.real + a.imag*b.imag
```

But I am very surprised not to find a nice ufunc to do this. Does it not exist? I was not expecting to have to write my own ufunc to vectorize such a common operation.

Part of my concern here, is that it seems like my expression is doing a lot of extra work extracting out the real/imaginary parts when they should be already in adjacent memory locations (considering a,b are actually already combined in a data type like complex64). This has the potential to cause a pretty severe slowdown.

** EDIT

Using Numba I ended up defining a ufunc:

```
@vectorize
def cdot(a, b):
    return (a.real*b.real + a.imag*b.imag)
```

This allowed me to correlate complex data properly. Here's a correlation image for the guys who helped me!

[image]

Comment: `1j*(-1j)` is `(1-0j)`

Comment: Your expression could be written less clumsily as `a.real*b.real + a.imag*b.imag`.

Comment: Could this be because the dot product of complex numbers is different to real numbers? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2459814/what-is-the-dot-product-of-complex-vectors

Comment: I think you have misunderstood the dot product in complex plane. Normally, `(1 + 1j) * (1 - 1j) == 2`, not `0`.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica or even `(a*b.conjugate()).real`

Comment: @Gorisanson - I am trying to take the dot product of complex numbers, treating it like x=real, y=imag. In other words, as if they were complex plane vectors.

Comment: @ColinMarcus You mean as if they were in real plane?

Comment: Lol yes. I'm sorry the terminology is getting in the way.

Comment: I found a web page that defines the dot of 2 complex numbers as: `(a * np.conj(b)).real`.  That seems to match your `reals + imag`.  https://www.bookofproofs.org/branches/dot-product-of-complex-numbers/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For arrays and `np.complex` scalars but not plain python `complex` numbers you can viewcast to float. For example:

```
a = np.exp(1j*np.arange(4))
b = np.exp(-1j*np.arange(4))
a
# array([ 1.        +0.j        ,  0.54030231+0.84147098j,
#        -0.41614684+0.90929743j, -0.9899925 +0.14112001j])
b
# array([ 1.        -0.j        ,  0.54030231-0.84147098j,
#        -0.41614684-0.90929743j, -0.9899925 -0.14112001j])
ar = a[...,None].view(float)
br = b[...,None].view(float)
ar
# array([[ 1.        ,  0.        ],
#        [ 0.54030231,  0.84147098],
#        [-0.41614684,  0.90929743],
#        [-0.9899925 ,  0.14112001]])
br
# array([[ 1.        , -0.        ],
#        [ 0.54030231, -0.84147098],
#        [-0.41614684, -0.90929743],
#        [-0.9899925 , -0.14112001]])
```

Now, for example, all pairwise dot products:

```
np.inner(ar,br)
# array([[ 1.        ,  0.54030231, -0.41614684, -0.9899925 ],
#        [ 0.54030231, -0.41614684, -0.9899925 , -0.65364362],
#        [-0.41614684, -0.9899925 , -0.65364362,  0.28366219],
#        [-0.9899925 , -0.65364362,  0.28366219,  0.96017029]])
```

Comment: This is really interesting! I take it viewcasting doesn't work for "plain python complex" because it doesn't store the real/imag numbers in adjacent memory addresses? And, does viewcasting work for arbitrarily large arrays of complex numbers, or does the address adjacency break down at some point?

Comment: @ColinMarcus I think it's more because python numbers do not implement the array interface. I'm not aware of the array size making any difference. That said I'm not 100% sure the memory layout is guaranteed. Might theoretically be an implementation detail.

Comment: Your `inner` equals `np.outer(a, np.conj(b)).real`.

Comment: @hpaulj yes, but takes half the arithmetic operations.